# Download html page and bind to a var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript and jquery.
I wonder if there are any ways to download content of a target html page.

And bind the downloaded content to a variable , and later I can search for its tags inside or not.

Can anyone give me an answer please ? :)
Thank you

Comment: What have you tried till nw??..You want the extension of  page to be downloaded strictly to be .html?..or .aspx will also work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can, using the jQuery 'load()' function: [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

If you want to load it into a variable instead of an element, you cah use the 'get' function. After you loaded the html into a variable, you can wrap it to get a jQuery element.

A simple example (just pseudocode, copy/paste probably won't work):

```
$.get("/example.html", function( data ) {
    var source = $(data);

   //and now you have a jQuery element. You can use 'find' to seach the including tags

}, 'html');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using HTMLAgilityPack to get the content from target html,like as

```
HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = htmlWeb.Load(url);
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"id('content')/div/div[1]/");
```

hopefully this help you.

Comment: What sorcery is this? this is not client side javascript